# Pigeon-hole principle question.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Consider a street with $17$ houses.

Show that we can demolish $12$ of the houses so that the remaining $5$ houses have the property that as one walks down the street, one sees

- either houses that get bigger and bigger
- or houses that get smaller and smaller.

This question was put on hold.

I have figured it out. This is based on Erdős–Szekeres theorem. here n = 4 , when 4^2+1 elements ,there will be 4+1 = 5 monotonic increasing or decreasing. [http://www.skidmore.edu/~adean/MC2151401/Handouts/ErdosSzekeresProof.pdf] 
 How can we remove put on hold to  add this answer separately

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have tried solving, but did not move forward much. Can some one please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You perhaps meant to assume all the houses are different sizes, as otherwise all houses being exactly the same size would give impossibility for either alternative.   You should explain (at a minimum) what you "tried solving".  Readers can then help you evaluate whether your approach can be made to succeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a hard problem.  Let me give you some hints.

First, you either have to assume that all the houses are different sizes, or that "bigger and bigger" means "not smaller," and "smaller and smaller" means "not bigger."

1. Label each house with an ordered pair $(i,d)$ where $i$ is the length of the longest increasing subsequence that starts at that house, and $d$ is the length of the longest decreasing subsequence that starts at that house.
2. Prove that no two houses have the same label.
3. Apply the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: I have figured it out. This is based on  Erdős–Szekeres theorem.  here n = 4 , when 4^2+1 elements ,there will be  4+1 = 5 monotonic increasing or decreasing.     http://www.skidmore.edu/~adean/MC2151401/Handouts/ErdosSzekeresProof.pdf

Comment: How to remove put on hold